# How can I install a driver?

Tags: drivers, kernel-modules

Although my ethernet card worked, I had very bad latency and speed. I looked up the hardware and I found [a driver](http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsview.aspx?langid=1&pnid=13&pfid=5&level=5&conn=4&downtypeid=3&getdown=false). Having run its [autorun.sh](http://pastebin.com/kR1fzasx) script makes the hardware work correctly. It loads the module by calling modprobe. However, I have to do this after every boot. How can I permanently install this module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the module to /etc/modules to make sure it's autoloaded at boot.
Use the following command

```
echo r8168 | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

or edit /etc/modules with your favorite text editor and add r8168 to the bottom.

After adding the module, the initial ramdisk should be updated with this driver, run:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```